# Braintree - Pass through custom data with a subscription

Tags: braintree

Is it possible to pass through custom data when creating a new subscription?

I can see it's possible and documentation for transaction::sale but I can't see anything for subscriptions:

https://developers.braintreepayments.com/javascript+php/guides/recurring-billing/create

If so what key values should I be setting inside

```
Braintree_Subscription::create
```

Answer (score 2):

I work as a developer for Braintree. Custom fields only exist as properties of [transactions](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/javascript+php/reference/request/transaction/sale#custom_fields) and [customers](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/javascript+php/reference/request/customer/create#use-custom-fields). They are not supported for subscriptions at this time.

Comment: Is there any chance this can be fixed in the future? I need to webhook callback from Subscriptions to have a bit more detail. And I would like the transaction custom fields to exist for subscriptions when downloading from your website.

Comment: It'd be nice to have a fix for this